# Items not getting centered in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I want to center the the contents of div, but the properties doesn't seems to work.
any idea why
here is my code

```html
<div class='center'>
    <form (ngSubmit)="loginUser()" style="background: steelblue;" class='login-form'>
        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='email' matInput placeholder="Email" name='email'>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='password' matInput placeholder="Password" name='password'>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <div class="button">
            <button type='submit' mat-raised-button>Login</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the style I'm trying to apply

```css
.center {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #ff1124;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

and this css

```css
.login-form .button button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #27803f;
    color: white
}
```

here is how my form appears
[image: Here is how my login page appears]

Comment: You only want to center the content of the div, so only the form tag? The code you have doesn't center the content inside the form.

Comment: I just want the entire form to be in the middle of screen

Comment: That is working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkdakz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html
Maybe you need to double-check the css code is being loaded. Is it in the component's styles file?

Comment: What is the CSS for .login-form? Also you have classes with single and double quotes, and while that shouldn't matter to the browser the general suggestion is to be consistent.

Comment: Yes, css properties are working as I'm able to change the color, 
Its just exploding my mind, I'm getting exhausted, tried a hell lot of ways but nothing going to work, can I share you my screen please

Comment: Edit your question to add the CSS for .login-form, and you can put an image of your screen in your question as well. But I suspect it's something to do with .login-form. If .login-form has auto margins, for instance, justify-content may not work correctly.

Comment: @JackArbiter I've updated the question, please check now

Comment: Try inspecting the element on chrome, right click on the element, and check the classes that are being applied to div container.

Comment: Remove width: 100% from .login-form, flex won't work if there's no extra space. If that's the problem I'll post as an answer.

Comment: width 100% is applied to the button right? That should not be a problem, it's still working in the example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkdakz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Ah I missed that. Confirmation bias, was looking for just .login-form's CSS.

Comment: yes width 100% is applied to button only, it should not be the problem,
I tried inspecting up to my knowledge and juggled around the elements there, but still not able to get the desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```css
.center {
    display: flex;
    background-color: 
    #ff1124;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.login-form .button button {
    width: 100%;
    background: #27803f;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
    <form (ngSubmit)="loginUser()" style="background: steelblue;" class='login-form'>
        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='email' matInput placeholder="Email" name='email'>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>

        <p>
            <mat-form-field>
                <input type="password" [(ngModel)]='password' matInput placeholder="Password" name='password'>
            </mat-form-field>
        </p>
        <div class="button">
            <button type='submit' mat-raised-button>Login</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: although its working here on SO engine, but it doesn't work for me :" (

Comment: How does it look in your end?

Comment: what possibly could be the issue

Comment: Try adding `width: 100vw;` in the center class

Comment: I just made it to work by using
`:host {
    width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
<div class="my-container">
  <div class='center'>
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your css :

```
.my-container {
  text-align:center;
  width: 100%;
}
```